# Issue while pushing package at heroku

Tags: meteor, heroku, npm

While trying to pushing package at heroku master I am receiving following error message.

Even if try to run meteor npm install command, then also I am receiving same error.

This is error received:

```
 npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-128-generic
 npm ERR! argv "/app/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.3_2.g6nepi++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-      os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node" "/app/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.3_2.g6nepi++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.8.0
npm ERR! npm v4.3.0
npm ERR! Cannot convert undefined or null to object
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR! https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
npm WARN deprecated sendgrid@4.10.0: Please see v6.X+ at https://www.npmjs.com/org/sendgrid
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /app/.npm/_logs/2017-09-13T13_55_52_109Z-debug.log
! Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
! Push failed >
```

These are packages installed

```
meteor-base@1.0.4 # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.4 # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates@1.0.4 # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
reactive-var@1.0.11 # Reactive variable for tracker
jquery@1.9.2 # Helpful client-side library
tracker@1.1.1 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

 standard-minifier-css@1.3.2 # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@1.2.1 # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.6.15 # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript@0.6.1 # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
shell-server@0.2.1 # Server-side component of the meteor shell command

email
meteoric:ionic
iron:router
fourseven:scss
stylus
ashutosh:email-att

session

dschulz:jquery-qrcode
mystor:device-detection

telerik:kendo-ui-core-default-theme
 froala:editor
fortawesome:fontawesome
percolate:synced-cron

http
ejson
mrgalaxy:stripe
meteorhacks:ssr

benan789:materialize-tagsinput

xvendo:tagit
matb33:bootstrap-tooltip

 glittershark:meteor-express
 lepozepo:s3

 materialize:materialize
accounts-google
service-configuration
accounts-facebook
pauli:accounts-linkedin
lukemadera:social-share

ostrio:cookies
benjaminrh:jquery-cookie

peerlibrary:aws-sdk
coffeescript
mizzao:jquery-ui
jparker:crypto-sha256

matdutour:popup-confirm
bratanon:recaptcha
jparker:crypto-hmac
jparker:crypto-aes
gadicohen:robots-txt
momentjs:moment
evucale:fast-levenshtein
themeteorchef:bert
```

This is package.json

```
{
"name": "JobApp",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"start": "meteor run"
},
"dependencies": {
 "Css": "0.0.1",
"async": "^2.1.5",
"aws-sdk": "^2.41.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
"babel-runtime": "^6.22.0",
 "dropbox": "^2.5.7",
"email-existence": "^0.1.5",
"express": "^4.15.1",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
 "heroku.node": "^0.2.1",
 "jquery": "^3.1.1",
  "js": "^0.1.0",
 "jsforce": "^1.7.1",
"meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0",
 "pg": "^6.1.5",
"pickadate": "~3.5.6",
"react-share": "^1.13.0",
"request": "^2.81.0",
"sendgrid": "^4.10.0",
"stripe": "^4.23.1",
"toastr": "^2.1.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"stripe-local": "^0.1.1"
 }
}
```

Meteor version is :1.4.3.2

Please tell how to resolve it, as I am sure this is not coding error as on local server (localhost) it is doing fine.

This is my npm-debug.log

```
 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
 1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install' ]
 2 info using npm@3.10.10
 3 info using node@v7.3.0
 4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
 5 silly install loadCurrentTree
 6 silly install readLocalPackageData
 7 silly install normalizeTree
 8 silly loadCurrentTree Finishing
 9 silly loadIdealTree Starting
 10 silly install loadIdealTree
 11 silly cloneCurrentTree Starting
 12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
 13 silly cloneCurrentTree Finishing
 14 silly loadShrinkwrap Starting
 15 silly install loadShrinkwrap
 16 silly loadShrinkwrap Finishing
 17 silly loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Starting
 18 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
 19 silly fetchNamedPackageData Css
 20 silly mapToRegistry name Css
 21 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
 22 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
 23 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
 23 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'Css',
 23 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,
 23 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: 'Css',
 23 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'Css',
 23 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
 23 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
 23 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
 24 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/Css
 25 silly fetchNamedPackageData pg
 26 silly mapToRegistry name pg
 27 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
 28 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
 29 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
 29 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'pg',
 29 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,
 29 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: 'pg',
 29 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'pg',
 29 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
 29 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
 29 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
 30 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/pg
 31 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/Css
 32 verbose request no auth needed
 33 info attempt registry request try #1 at 7:41:42 PM
 34 verbose request id 8a0defa59d360214
 35 verbose etag W/"598d06e6-179"
 36 verbose lastModified Fri, 11 Aug 2017 01:22:46 GMT
 37 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/Css
 38 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/pg
 39 verbose request no auth needed
 40 info attempt registry request try #1 at 7:41:42 PM
 41 verbose etag W/"59b95a15-3478e"
42 verbose lastModified Wed, 13 Sep 2017 16:17:25 GMT
43 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pg
44 http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pg
45 verbose headers { date: 'Thu, 14 Sep 2017 14:12:25 GMT',
45 verbose headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
45 verbose headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
45 verbose headers   etag: 'W/"59b95a15-3478e"',
45 verbose headers   age: '99',
45 verbose headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
45 verbose headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-sin18024-SIN',
45 verbose headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
45 verbose headers   'x-cache-hits': '1',
45 verbose headers   'x-timer': 'S1505398345.468788,VS0,VE0',
45 verbose headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding, Accept' }
46 silly get cb [ 304,
46 silly get   { date: 'Thu, 14 Sep 2017 14:12:25 GMT',
46 silly get     via: '1.1 varnish',
46 silly get     'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
46 silly get     etag: 'W/"59b95a15-3478e"',
46 silly get     age: '99',
46 silly get     connection: 'keep-alive',
46 silly get     'x-served-by': 'cache-sin18024-SIN',
46 silly get     'x-cache': 'HIT',
46 silly get     'x-cache-hits': '1',
46 silly get     'x-timer': 'S1505398345.468788,VS0,VE0',
46 silly get     vary: 'Accept-Encoding, Accept' } ]
47 verbose etag https://registry.npmjs.org/pg from cache
48 verbose get saving pg to /home/astrea/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/pg/.cache.json
49 verbose correctMkdir /home/astrea/.npm correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
50 silly resolveWithNewModule pg@6.4.2 checking installable status
51 silly cache add args [ 'pg@^6.1.5', null ]
52 verbose cache add spec pg@^6.1.5
53 silly cache add parsed spec Result {
53 silly cache add   raw: 'pg@^6.1.5',
53 silly cache add   scope: null,
53 silly cache add   escapedName: 'pg',
53 silly cache add   name: 'pg',
53 silly cache add   rawSpec: '^6.1.5',
53 silly cache add   spec: '>=6.1.5 <7.0.0',
53 silly cache add   type: 'range' }
54 silly addNamed pg@>=6.1.5 <7.0.0
55 verbose addNamed ">=6.1.5 <7.0.0" is a valid semver range for pg
56 silly addNameRange { name: 'pg', range: '>=6.1.5 <7.0.0', hasData: false }
57 silly mapToRegistry name pg
58 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
59 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
60 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
60 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'pg',
60 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,
60 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: 'pg',
60 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'pg',
60 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
60 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
60 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
61 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/pg
62 verbose addNameRange registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/pg not in flight; fetching
 63 verbose get https://registry.npmjs.org/pg not expired, no request
 64 silly addNameRange number 2 { name: 'pg', range: '>=6.1.5 <7.0.0', hasData: true }
 65 silly addNameRange versions [ 'pg',
 65 silly addNameRange   [ '0.4.1',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.5.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.5.1',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.5.2',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.5.3',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.5.4',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.5.5',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.5.6',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.5.7',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.5.8',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.1',
65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.2',
65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.3',
65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.4',
65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.5',
65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.6',
65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.7',
65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.8',
65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.9',
65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.10',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.11',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.12',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.13',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.14',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.15',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.16',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.17',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.6.18',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.7.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.7.1',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.7.2',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.8.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.8.1',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.8.2',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.8.3',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.8.4',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.8.6',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.8.7',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.8.8',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.9.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.10.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.10.2',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.11.1',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.11.2',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.11.3',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.12.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.12.1',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.12.3',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.13.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.13.1',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.13.3',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.14.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.14.1',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.15.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '0.15.1',
 65 silly addNameRange     '1.0.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '1.0.1',
 65 silly addNameRange     '1.0.2',
 65 silly addNameRange     '1.0.3',
 65 silly addNameRange     '1.0.4',
 65 silly addNameRange     '1.1.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '1.1.1',
 65 silly addNameRange     '1.1.2',
 65 silly addNameRange     '1.1.3',
 65 silly addNameRange     '1.2.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '1.3.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.0.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.1.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.2.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.3.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.3.1',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.4.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.5.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.5.1',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.6.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.6.1',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.6.2',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.7.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.8.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.8.1',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.8.2',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.8.3',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.8.4',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.8.5',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.9.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.10.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.11.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '2.11.1',
 65 silly addNameRange     '3.0.2',
 65 silly addNameRange     '3.0.3',
 65 silly addNameRange     '3.1.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '3.2.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '3.3.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '3.4.0',
 65 silly addNameRange     '3.4.1',
 65 silly addNameRange     '3.4.2',
 65 silly addNameRange     '3.4.3',
 65 silly addNameRange     '3.4.4',
 65 silly addNameRange     '3.4.5',
 65 silly addNameRange     ... 63 more items ] ]
 66 silly addNamed pg@6.4.2
 67 verbose addNamed "6.4.2" is a plain semver version for pg
 68 silly cache afterAdd pg@6.4.2
 69 verbose afterAdd /home/astrea/.npm/pg/6.4.2/package/package.json not in flight; writing
 70 verbose correctMkdir /home/astrea/.npm correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
 71 verbose afterAdd /home/astrea/.npm/pg/6.4.2/package/package.json written
 72 http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/Css
 73 verbose headers { date: 'Thu, 14 Sep 2017 14:12:25 GMT',
 73 verbose headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
 73 verbose headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
 73 verbose headers   etag: 'W/"598d06e6-179"',
 73 verbose headers   age: '0',
 73 verbose headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
 73 verbose headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-sin18035-SIN',
 73 verbose headers   'x-cache': 'MISS',
 73 verbose headers   'x-cache-hits': '0',
 73 verbose headers   'x-timer': 'S1505398345.468761,VS0,VE207',
 73 verbose headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding, Accept' }
 74 silly get cb [ 304,
 74 silly get   { date: 'Thu, 14 Sep 2017 14:12:25 GMT',
 74 silly get     via: '1.1 varnish',
 74 silly get     'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
 74 silly get     etag: 'W/"598d06e6-179"',
 74 silly get     age: '0',
 74 silly get     connection: 'keep-alive',
 74 silly get     'x-served-by': 'cache-sin18035-SIN',
 74 silly get     'x-cache': 'MISS',
 74 silly get     'x-cache-hits': '0',
 74 silly get     'x-timer': 'S1505398345.468761,VS0,VE207',
 74 silly get     vary: 'Accept-Encoding, Accept' } ]
 75 verbose etag https://registry.npmjs.org/Css from cache
 76 verbose get saving Css to /home/astrea/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/Css/.cache.json
  77 verbose correctMkdir /home/astrea/.npm correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
 78 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
 78 verbose stack     at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
 78 verbose stack     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:125:29)
 78 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
 78 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/pulse-till-done.js:20:8
 78 verbose stack     at saved (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/caching-client.js:174:7)
 78 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:241:18
  78 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:111:15)
  79 verbose cwd /home/astrea/prachi/JOBAPP/sep14/herokujobapp
  80 error Linux 3.19.0-30-generic
  81 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
   82 error node v7.3.0
  83 error npm  v3.10.10
  84 error Cannot convert undefined or null to object
  85 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
  85 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
  86 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Perhaps, you can also share this debug log from `npm` fail?

Comment: I have added my npm-debug.log in above question.

Comment: @PrachiAgarwal write this command `heroku logs -a APPNAME` and give me that log

Comment: @kumbhanibhavesh right now I am testing my app after removing Css package as mentioned by Styx. If it will further create any problem then I will send logs to you.

Comment: @PrachiAgarwal :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your issue is with this package:

**`package.json`**:

```
"Css": "0.0.1"
```

This package's info from registry is:

```
{
  "_id":"Css",
  "_rev":"2-991135127ed2a59900aa51542c7ab23a",
  "name":"Css",
  "time": {
    "modified":"2017-08-11T01:22:46.337Z",
    "created":"2016-05-31T05:10:21.441Z",
    "0.0.1":"2016-05-31T05:10:21.441Z",
    "unpublished": {
      "name":"npm",
      "time":"2017-08-11T01:22:46.337Z",
      "tags":{ "latest": "0.0.1" },
      "maintainers":[
        {
          "name":"zhengzk",
          "email":"studyc@163.com"
        }
      ],
      "versions": [ "0.0.1" ]
    }
  },
  "_attachments":{}
}
```

As you can see there is no `versions` document and *that* causes mentioned error, according to this [comment in `npm`'s issue about this error](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9896#issuecomment-263712713)

If you don't need it at all — just remove this package from `dependencies`.

Comment: Thank you @Styx method mentioned by you has worked for me. Now my app is online. But I will accept your answer after testing, if my app doesn't create any issue because of removing that package.

Comment: @PrachiAgarwal Glad it helped :)